# how to create jboss fuse admin user

Tags: jboss

i am trying to install **jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379**
and i am able to create esb:create-admin-user via console but not i am trying to automate installation via shell script .
i am able to start fuse server but not able to create user

> esb:create-admin-user.

below is sample script for creating user.

## !/bin/ksh

cd $HOME/jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379/bin

./fuse esb:create-admin-user --new-user admin1 --new-user-password admin12

but it is not creating user.

please let me know how i can do this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `bin/client` script to execute commands against a running fuse instance. But for that you will need a username/password ;)

If you want to automate it is indeed probably easier just to use @mahesh-biradar approach:

```
echo "admin1=admin12,admin" >> etc/users.properties
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be the issue with file write access present in etc .

**Here is the another solution for that**

1. Go to *jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379/etc* folder
2. Open users.properties file and add username=password,admin
3. Last word admin is the "**Admin**" role.